# Winforms checkedlistbox check one item

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a `CheckedListBox` control on my form, and I want the user to only be able to check one item at a time within this list (so effectively I'd want something that would mimic a "RadioListBox").

Is this possible to do with a `CheckedListBox` or would I have to improvise doing it some other way?

The `CheckedListBox` is populated on the form load by loading items from a database, in case that matters.

Thanks

**Edit**

I think I should clarify, I am not looking to limit the amount a user can SELECT (ie the SelectionMode property), rather how many they can CHECK.

Comment: Why use a checked listbox then. You could just use a simple listbox.

Comment: The user specifically asked to be able to "check" unfortunately. If there doesn't prove to be an easy way to limit the number of items that can be checked at once then I'll just use a normal listbox as you say.

Comment: Use a ComboBox instead.  DropDownStyle = Simple if you really want a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by adding an event check on CheckedListBox for ItemCheck and use function like this:

```
    private static bool checkIfAllowed(CheckedListBox listBox) {
        if (listBox.CheckedItems.Count > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then in the event you would have like:

```
  if (checkIfAllowed) { 
     ...
  } else {

  }
```

Additionally you could improve this by adding another function/method that will uncheck all items before allowing item to be checked. So when users click some checkbox all other checkboxes are unchecked.

To uncheck all checked items just use:

```
    private static void uncheckAll(CheckedListBox listBox) {
        IEnumerator myEnumerator;
        myEnumerator = listBox.CheckedIndices.GetEnumerator();
        int y;
        while (myEnumerator.MoveNext() != false) {
            y = (int)myEnumerator.Current;
            listBox.SetItemChecked(y, false);
        }
    }
```

So in ItemCheck event you would have to run `uncheckAll(yourListBox)` first and then simply let the item be checked.

Edit:
I've tested it with following code and it works. Without the if it throws exception.

```
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked) {
            IEnumerator myEnumerator;
            myEnumerator = checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.GetEnumerator();
            int y;
            while (myEnumerator.MoveNext() != false) {
                y = (int)myEnumerator.Current;
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(y, false);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Madboy, however the uncheckAll method causes a StackOverflowException to be thrown - every time you cann SetItemChecked the ItemChecked event is triggered, which means the uncheckAll is continually triggered as well. Unless I've forgotten to do something?

Answer (score 1):

Try set [`.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.selectionmode%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Comment: This only lets me select one item at a time (ie highlight), it doesn't control how many items can be checked at any time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar to select a single user from a massive list. There isn't a RadioListBox to speak of, so I just coded it manually...

Sorry it's in VB, I just pasted it in, the logic is the same.

```
Private m_NoFire As Boolean = False

Private Sub lstSource_ItemCheck( _
        ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles lstSource.ItemCheck

    'When the checked state is set programatically,
    'this event will still fire and cause the loop
    'to run - infinatly. This line prevents that.
    If m_NoFire Then Exit Sub
    m_NoFire = True

    'Ensure only one item is selected
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstSource.Items.Count - 1
        If Not lstSource.SelectedIndex = i Then
            lstSource.SetItemChecked(i, False)
        End If
    Next

    m_NoFire = False

End Sub '-- lstSource_ItemCheck
```

Comment: KMan just posted a much better way. Still, this code has been in the project for about 5 years and I ain't changing it now :D

Comment: @KMan on second thoughts, looking at that link I don't think it limits checking, only selection.

Answer (score 0):

This code is could be much more simple, requires one variable.
Every time you will check a new box, it will uncheck the last one, leading to the fact that there won't be two checked items or more checked at the time.
Make sure the property `SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;` is set as mentioned.

```
    private int lastCheck = -1;
    private void CheckListBox_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int toUncheck = lastCheck;
        if (toUncheck != -1)
            CheckListBox.SetItemChecked(toUncheck, false);
        lastCheck = CheckListBox.SelectedIndex;
        CheckListBox.SetItemChecked(lastCheck, true);
    }
```

Or alternativly you could set lastCheck to the default checked box if required, do this by:

```
    private void FormFoo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CheckListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        lastCheck = CheckListBox.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

and then the rest of the code that I mentioned above comes below.

Notice*: I've used `lastCheck = **CheckListBox.SelectedIndex;**` to support keyboard moving, just in case.